# Fork() command issue

Tags: c, linux, fork

While going thorough fork() command i got struck with a question .

how many no.of processes are created by the end of 12th second, if
time starts from 0th second? Process id's start from 0.

**Pseudo code**

```
 while(true)
        {
             sleep 1second;
             if( getpid() % 2 == 0 )
             {
                     fork();
                     printf("Hello\n");
             }
       }
```

when i run above code on my system it is not showing output on konsole. Is  no . of process at end  of 12 sec is dependent on OS ?Need suggestion as i am not good in fork()

Comment: `getpid()` is not a process counter. pids can (and should, even if they usually aren't) be assigned in random order. Nothing can be said about this program's output.

Answer (score 2):

Since when do process IDs "start at 0"? Not even when the system boots; the first process has the id 1 :-)

You're only fork()ing when your own process ID is even; so if it happens to be odd then nothing will happen... which means that if you run the program several times, sometimes it will do something and sometimes it won't.

Answer (score 1):

Add this after your `printf`:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

But you have a fundamental problem with your logic. `fork()` returns 0 in the child, and the child pid in the parent. You don't check, so both the parent and the child continue doing the loop, which happens again, and again, and again, forever. You need to change the loop body to this:

```
if(fork() == 0)
{
  printf("Hello!\n");
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: Yeah !! Now its printing but infinite loop. That means no. of process after 12 sec is infinite ,it sound weird or i mis-understood something  ?

Comment: @sharaddixit: Your loop never ends. If you want it to only go for ~12 seconds, use a for loop instead of the while of this form: `for(int i=0; i <12; i++)`.

Comment: Even then it is either showing nothing or printing infinite hello. Why not finite "hello" even with limited for loop?